# Interaction with a deployed smart contract from the geth command line

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, web3js, contract-deployment, abi

I have a contract which I'd like to be able to sum numbers submitted by any other address:

```
contract UnitCounter {
    mapping (address => uint256) public UnitsFrom;
    uint256 public TotalUnits;

    function submitUnits(uint256 Units) {
        UnitsFrom[msg.sender] = Units;
        TotalUnits += Units;
    }
}
```

Using [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#example-50) as rough guidance, I followed the following steps on a private-net:

1. Deploy the contract using mist
2. Get the JSON Interface code using the "Show Interface" icon in mist
3. Copy the address of the deployed contract `0x17d541b8aACFFe473e3dD32eBA83C82B51DB8EF9` on my private blockchain.
4. On a Geth console:

   `var abi=[ { "constant": false, "inputs": [ { "name": "Units", "type": "uint256" } ], "name": "submitUnits", "outputs": [], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [], "name": "TotalUnits", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256" } ], "type": "function" }, { "constant": true, "inputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "address" } ], "name": "UnitsFrom", "outputs": [ { "name": "", "type": "uint256", "value": "0" } ], "type": "function" } ]`

   ```
   var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

   var MyContractInstance = MyContract.at('0x17d541b8aACFFe473e3dD32eBA83C82B51DB8EF9');

   MyContractInstance.submitUnits('10');
   ```

I then get the following errors:

> Error: invalid address
>   
>         at web3.js:3887:15
>   
>         at web3.js:3713:20
>   
>         at web3.js:4939:28
>   
>         at map ()
>   
>         at web3.js:4938:12
>   
>         at web3.js:4964:18
>   
>         at web3.js:4989:23
>   
>         at web3.js:4055:16
>   
>         at apply ()
>   
>         at web3.js:4141:16

**What do these errors mean?**

**How should I debug from this point?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add a transaction object to tell geth what account to use for the transaction:

```
MyContractInstance.submitUnits('10', {from: eth.accounts[0], gas:3000000});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also make this error go away this way, where you set your default account, so you don't have to add options {from:...} while interacting with your contract.

In your **geth console** :-

```
// default account set to first account in your geth accounts
eth.defaultAccount = eth.accounts[0]
// Note: If eth.accounts is empty, you can create a new account with personal.newAccount()
```

```
// default account set to coinbase(Etherbase), the default primary local account in geth
eth.defaultAccount = eth.coinbase
```

If you get this error next subsequently - *Error: authentication needed: password or unlock*, unlock your account.

In your **geth console** :-

```
// unlocks your account for calls/transactions after you give password 
personal.unlockAccount(eth.defaultAccount)
```