# Point testrpc to a custom genesis file

Tags: contract-development, private-blockchain, testnets, contract-debugging, testrpc

Following [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11164/820), I'm using testrpc to create a large number of unlocked accounts:

```
testrpc -a 1000
```

This seems to create a new blockchain.

Is there a command option to point it to a custom genesis file or data directory? I can't find it in [the docs](https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc#usage). Perhaps there is something akin to the [`datadir` command option](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) for geth.

Comment: I think testrpc has no data directory

Comment: @RolandKofler ah ok. A misunderstanding on my part. Thanks