# Run code on an open geth command line, but initiated from OS command line

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-debugging, testrpc, command-line

Say I have testrpc set up:

```
testrpc -a 10
```

and have attached a geth console:

```
geth attach rpc:http://localhost:8545
```

If I want to run a contract call from the open geth console, but call it from the OS (windows in my case) command line, how might I do it?

e.g this command (contract from [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10405/interaction-with-a-deployed-smart-contract-from-the-geth-command-line)).

`> UnitCounter.submitUnits(72,{from:eth.coinbase,gas:3000000})`

Comment: You can use NodeJS + web3 for this, instead of the built-in console.

Comment: When you attach, you get a console, right? Your command will work as long as the `UnitCounter` instance has been created.

Comment: @XavierLeprêtreB9lab Yes, but I'd like to call that command from outside geth. Eg. in python pseudocode; `import os     os.cmd('geth command UnitCounter.submitUnits(72,{from:eth.coinbase,gas:3000000})'`. As TjandenHess points out, this should be possible with NodeJS+web3.